# Is there a way to automatically add new properties to my c# model class when there is a change in number of fields in the mysql table?

Tags: c#, .net-core, model

I have a mysql table that contains questions and answers, to which monthly or weekly new questions get added. So I need my model class to get updated according to the number of fields in the table.
I am using dot net core 6, dapper micro-orm and mysql. I saw the use of `dynamic` or `ExpandoObject` but I fear that I cannot use them because I have several other operations using these model classes not just insertion and selection from database.

An example of my model class:

```
public class Questions{
  public long Id {....}
  public int Question1 {....}
  public int Question2 {....}
  .
  .
  public int Question10 {....}
 }
```

Now when a 11th question is added to the database table, a new property should be added to my model class.

Comment: I think a list, or any sort of collection, would be better suited to your problem. As far as I know (don't take my word for it) you can't do it the way you are trying to.

Comment: When you say 11th question added, you mean a new column is added to the table?

Comment: When you say 11th question added, you mean a new column is added to the table? Yes Chetan

Answer (score 2):

If with "a 11th question is added to the database table" you meant a new column, that's a **bad design choice**. You don't add columns to add new content, that's what rows are for.

You should set up your table to have a column *Question* and a column *Answer* instead of adding a column each time. This way you can just add a row with the proper values.

As for C#, you should use a collection to handle these situations. Here is just an example of what you can make your class look like:

```
public class QuestionWithAnswer {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

And then you get a List of objects of this type from the database using whichever method you'd like, in your case Dapper.

Your SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Question, Answer
FROM Questions
```